# Is there any post-hoc explainable AI method for complex CNN-base architectures e.g. Mask R-CNN?

Tags: faster-rcnn, posthoc, xai

Is there any posthoc easily applicable explainable AI tool for detections carried out by complex CNN-base architectures e.g. Mask R-CNN?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PyTorch, I can recommend the following repo: https://github.com/jacobgil/pytorch-grad-cam. You have many tutorials, explanations and different xAI methods.